# Issues with passing structures into functions

Tags: c, pointers, stack, push, structure

I have several years of experience with java, but I'm very new to C. I'm still struggling to figure out when and when not to use pointers. I was given this base code and need to finish the 'push' method so that it pushes the next element onto the stack, but I'm getting errors saying:

request for member 'top' in something not a structure.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <libgen.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int exit_status = EXIT_SUCCESS;
#define EMPTY (-1)
#define SIZE 16

typedef struct stack stack;
   struct stack {
   int top;
   double numbers[SIZE];
};

void push (stack *the_stack, double number) {
    if(&&the_stack.top>=SIZE-1){
       printf("error");
    }else{
       the_stack.numbers[&&the_stack.top++ ] = number;
    }
}
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  if (argc != 1) {
     fprintf (stderr, "Usage: %s\n", basename (argv[0]));
     fflush (NULL);
     exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
stack the_stack;
the_stack.top = EMPTY;
char buffer[1024];
for (;;) {
   int scanrc = scanf ("%1023s", buffer);
   if (scanrc == EOF) break;
   assert (scanrc == 1);
   if (buffer[0] == '#') {
     scanrc = scanf ("%1023[^\n]", buffer);
     continue;
  }
  char *endptr;
  double number = strtod (buffer, &endptr);
  if (*endptr == '\0') {
     push (&the_stack, number);
  }else if (buffer[1] != '\0') {
     bad_operator (buffer);
  }else {
     do_operator (&the_stack, buffer);
  }
}
 return exit_status;
}
```

Am I overlooking something very basic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When accessing members of a structure, there are two operators: The dot operator `.` which is used for non-pointer structures, and the "arrow" operator `->` which is used for pointers to structures.

You have a pointer to a structure in your `push` function, so you need to use the "arrow" operator.

---

There are other problems with your code, like the double ampersand in the `push` function. You also don't need to flush any files when exiting the program, the runtime will do that for you.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't realize there were different ways to fetch fields depending on if you're working with a pointer or the structure itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
It seems very clearly that you have less experience in C. There are lots of compile time errors in your code like for example :
```

In push function top and numbers should be invoked as : 
the_stack->top
the_stack->numbers[]
An arrow is used to invoke the members of a pointer variable.

Now Comparing it with Java:
Java uses only references not pointers. But internally they are pointing to some location in memory.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qfk86yb3drdlmz2/C%20to%20Java.JPG     Image
http://erikdemaine.org/papers/CPE98/paper.pdf                   Paper

Check this link to correlate C code and Java code.